# How can I use an else if statement to compare letters and make it case insensitive?

Tags: c++, if-statement, equals

So I have this block of code here:

```
string answer1;

answerQues1:    
    cout << "So, A, B, C or D?";
    cin >> answer1;

     if (answer1 == "A" | answer1 == "a")
        {
            cout << "It's the right answer, you have " << char(156) << "100!" << endl;
            PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£100correct.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC );
            Sleep(2000);
        }

    else if (answer1 >= "E" | answer1 >= "e") //FIX THIS, IT'S ONLY ACCEPTING CAPITALS NOT LOWERCASES.
        {
            cout << "Whoops, you've entered an incorrect option! Remember, only A, B, C or D are acceptable." << endl;
            answer1.erase();
            goto answerQues1;
        }    

     else
        {
            cout << "I'm very sorry, it's an early exit for you - it's the wrong answer! You leave with nothing!" << endl;
            PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/£100and£64000lose.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            Sleep (4000);
            PlaySound(TEXT("C:/Users/user/Downloads/Millionaire/gameOver.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
            cout << "Thanks for playing! Press any key to exit the game" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
```

The else if statement checks if the answer is greater or equal to the letter E, since only A, B, C or D are acceptable. It then displays a message telling the user, deletes the value of answer1, and then goes back to the input section, essentially making an loop. However, when I enter an incorrect option such as E and immediately enter a acceptable one such as B  it does not accept B as a wrong answer and instead of going to the else statement, it goes to the else if ONLY IF THE ANSWER IS LOWERCASE. But if I typed B in capitals, it treats it as wrong and goes to the else statement as it should. Is there anyway I can fix this so it will detect upper and lowercase letters? Many thanks.

Comment: Why not just uppercase or lowercase the input first?

Comment: Logical OR is ||, not |. 'e'>='E', so answer>="e" is true for answer="B".

Comment: Ed, I was thinking about that but the user may have their preferences so I don't want the program to mess up and treat the answer as wrong because they put an answer in a different case, I want to try accommodate for every possibility :)

Comment: @SGCSam but you are currently treating upper and lowercase as the same so why not just upper or lower case the input and compare against a single value, saying that the upper and lower case value of 'E' will trap 'B' character so it won't work, you'd need to handle those conditions separately

Comment: Yeah that could work as well, however I think wolfPack88 got it to work as well, but thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is lower case letters are greater than upper case letters. See the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/. You probably want:

```
else if ((answer1 >= "E" && answer1 <= "Z") || answer1 >= "e")
```

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot man, I'll try that now and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

First, logical OR is ||, not |.

Second, take a look at an ASCII table and you'll see that 'e'>'E', so for answer="b" your check answer>"E" is true. You should better check that the value in an allowed range, so also give an end value.

Also: If you are only accepting one character as a choice, then make answer a char and not a string.

So a better solution would be

```
char answer;

if(answer == 'A'  ||  answer == 'a')
   ...
if(!(('A' <= answer  && answer <= 'D')  ||  ('a' <= answer  && answer <= 'd'))
   ...
```

You might also consider using the `toupper`/`tolower` functions on answer before checking the value.

And if you want it really safe, then keep in mind that ASCII is not the only encoding and not every character encoding assures that 'A'+1=='B' and 'B'+1=='C' and so on (EBCDIC for example is another character encoding where 'A'-'I' are in order, then there is a gap and than come 'J'-'R'). OK, I know, ASCII is *the* standard encoding, but it's not the worst idea to know the possible pitfalls :).

Comment: The answer should be passed to `toupper` or `tolower` before any comparisons are made.

Comment: Ah, so toupper basically converts it to it's upper case equivalent which then removes the need to check both cases?

Comment: @SGCSam: Yes, that's how you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

All strings are in some order, like "0" < "A" < "B" < "C" < "D" < "E" < "X" ... < "a" < "b" < "c" < "d" < "e" < "x" and so on.

All the lowercase letters come *after* the letter "E", that's why your test goes wrong. Test *first* for the acceptable answers, that is "A" and "a" as you did, then "B", "b", ... "d", and everything else is unacceptable.

Comment: The better method is to convert the letter to uppercase or lower case before comparing.  This eliminates 1/2 of the compare expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only going to accept A,B,C or D then why not accept the input as a `char` and convert it to a lower character. Admittedly, you can also do so with `string` - one char at a time.

Anyways, here's a sample for char:

```
char answer1;
std::cout << "So, A, B, C or D?";
std::cin >> answer1;
char lower = tolower(answer1);
std::cout <<" You entered: " << lower << std::endl;
```

Comment: The problem is when I try this, the double equals in the if's say "operand types are incompatable"

Comment: Try something like this: `if (lower == 'a')`. `char` types should be single quotes. Double quotes identify a `string`